# How to write test for a button inside a list tag? Unable to get the button element inside a ui tag?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

checkResult is a helper function which is imported in my component.jsx

component.jsx

```
return(
<ul>
  {options.map((option) => {
    return (
      <li key={option.value}>
        <button
          data-testid="unlock-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            checkResult()
              ? lunch(option.value)
              : showError();
          }}
        >
          {option.label}
        </button>
      </li>
    );
  })}
</ul>;
)
```

my test

```
import * as helper  from "../helpers/checkResult";

    it("fires action when lunch is clicked", async () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(helper, 'checkResult');
        let component;
        await act(async()=>{
            component = <component /> ;
        })
        await expect(screen.queryByTestId("unlock-btn"));
        fireEvent.click(screen.queryByTestId("unlock-btn"));
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
```

this is the error i'm getting

> Unable to fire a "click" event - please provide a DOM element.

i have also provided my getComponent Method above

Comment: is it ok if the "component" is in lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing `options` to the component so it has nothing to render. You're also using a map to render a list of items all of which have the same `id`. You should do something like

```
map((option, index) => {
   return (
     <li key={option.value}>
       <button
         data-testid=`unlock-btn-${index}`
```

This way you can target each individual option by ID in your test.

Edit: Your `fireEvent` is not defined in your example either.

Comment: how would I target them with id?

Comment: `await expect(screen.queryByTestId("unlock-btn-1"));`

Comment: I'm still not getting the button element. It's giving me null

Comment: You still have no passed any options into your component. You are rendering `<component />` where are the options coming from?

Comment: i'm passing option as a defaultProps to my component.  <SchedulePicker {...defaultProps}{...props}/>.

Comment: I don't see any of that in the provided examples.

Comment: I just updated my test, hope you find that useful Micky

Comment: @Junga did you mean to call `getComponent()` instead of `<component />`. You might as well copy/paste your actual code as there's nothing here that would be sensitive information. I can't really tell what you've tried as the ID's still sharing the same value. You can't have more than 1 element in your DOM with the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

The right way would be using the aria-label and attributes to be able to select those buttons without the need of data-testid.

```
<button
  onClick={() => { checkResult() ? lunch(option.value): showError();}}
  name={option.label} // assuming the labels are unique
>
{option.label}
</button>
```

then:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

it('Should do some test', ()=>{
  render(<MyComponent/>)
  const button = screen.getByRole('button', {name: "some-label"})
  fireEvent.click(button)
  expect(....).toBe(...)
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: If it didn't work for you, you are welcome to share which part so we can all learn from it

Comment: i'm still not able to get the button element with getByroles